# List Entries by Author

Tags: author

We would like to show a page which lists all Authors, and their respective entries, eg.

Dan Griffey

- Entry 1
- Entry 2

Joe Blogs

- Entry 1
- Entry 2

Have tried a few options but alas none working, so would appreciate any help / examples.

Comment: Are you trying to output a list of authors that have entries in a particular section, or is it site-wide?

Comment: Just as per the below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the [`group`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#group) filter:

```
{% for author, entries in craft.entries.find() | group('author') %}
    {{ author }}
    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
              <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```